# When is $my_array different from \@my_array?

Tags: perl

Say I define an array as:

```
my @my_array = ["hello", "world"]
```

Is there any difference between using `$my_array` vs `\@my_array` later in my code?

I presume that they are both are scalar references to `@array`, but I think I have seen one of my programs behaving differently depending on which one I use.

Is there any difference at all between them?

Comment: Please show us how you are defining `$my_array` in the suspect code.  You've gotten fairly comprehensive `perlref` introductions as answers, but they're not helping.  Seeing the difference *in your code* would help us to comment on the differences you expect or don't expect.  (Indeed, right now I'd say that the main difference in the code you've shown is that `$my_array` will explode under `use strict`. :))

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- `@array` is array
- `$var` is scalar
- `\@array` is scalar - reference to array `@array`
- `("hello", "world")` is list (compatible with `@array`)
- `["hello", "world"]` scalar, reference to array. It is the same as storing array `("hello", "world")` in variable `@array` and then taking reference `\@array` from it.

When you use:

```
my $my_array = ["hello", "world"]
```

you create variable `$my_array` which is reference to array `("hello", "world")`.

When you use:

```
my @my_array = ["hello", "world"]
```

you create an array which contains single element: reference to array `("hello", "world")`.

Comment: Your fifth bullet point is false.  `\("hello", "world")` is the same as `(\"hello", \"world")`.

Comment: Thanks mvp.  I take from this that there is no difference between `\@my_array` and `$my_array` then? I have updated the OP to clarify any potential confusion.

Comment: @user815423426: no, they are quite different. For example, while you can use statement `my $array;`, you cannot use `my \@array;` - it won't compile. Again, `$array` is scalar variable, `@array` is list variable, while `\@array` is scalar value (not variable!) that is reference to an array.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a difference between `\@my_array` and `$my_array`? It depends:

```
my @my_array = qw(hello world); #Note the use of parentheses
my $my_array = "Hello, I am just some random string!";
```

In the above case, there is a difference between `\@my_array` and `$my_array`. Likeness in variable names don't necessarily imply a relationship.

However:

```
my @my_array qw(hello world);
my $my_array = \@my_array;
```

`\@my_array` and `$my_array` would be identical. A change in `@my_array` would be reflected in the reference `$my_array`.

In your code you have:

```
my @my_array = ["hello", "world"];
```

Which is really a strange syntax...

`[...]` syntax is defining a *reference* to an array. Most of the time, you'd see something like this:

```
my $array_ref = ["hello", "world"];  #Note the assignment to a scalar and not an array
```

or this:

```
my @my_array = ("hello", "world");  #Note the parentheses and not straight brackets
```

Look at this program using [Data::Dumper](http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);
use Data::Dumper;
my @my_array = ["hello", "world"];
say Dumper \@my_array;
```

The output is:

```
$VAR1 = [
      [
        'hello',
        'world'
      ]
    ];
```

What this is saying is that there's an array of a single element (that is, your `@my_array` only contains `$my_array[0]`), and that element in that array is a reference to another array that contains two elements 'hello', and 'world'.